# What do Claw Blades cost?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So my Catfolk rogue wants Claw Blades.
You can find the [description of claw blades here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/claw-blades), but I can't find the listing price anywhere.

What do they cost?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### 305gp

The weapon is indeed not listed in the [weapons table on d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons). That is not actually surprising, the whole weapons section of that site is in serious need of a re-do.

Luckily, the [official PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/) is sorted like the books are. Claw Blades are listed under Catfolk Equipment on the [Catfolk](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/featuredRaces/catfolk.html#catfolk-equipment) page, for 305 gp per paw. Claw Blades are always treated as masterwork weapons, hence the unusual and high price.

Comment: Google just confirmed that the price is not on d20pfsrd. ["Claw Blades"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:d20pfsrd.com+%22claw+blades%22) is only found in 3 locations, none of which has the price.